# Accessing values in nested dictionaries within multiple files?

Tags: python, json, list, file

I have a folder with twenty .png file and a .json file each.
The .json file looks like below

```
{
"ID":12,
"flags"={},
"shapes":[
{"label":"text",
"points":[[65, 14],[27, 40]],
}
],
"flags"={},
"shapes":[
{"label":"logo",
"points":[[165, 124],[207, 43]],
}
],
"flags"={},
"shapes":[
{"label":"text",
"points":[[54, 24],[17, 53]],
}
]
}
```

I want to make a list of all the "label"s in each file. How can I do this?

I tried

```
import os
import json

path_to_json = './'
contents=[]

for file_name in [file for file in os.listdir(path_to_json) if file.endswith('.json')]:
    with open(path_to_json + file_name) as json_file:
        data=json.load(json_file)
        contents.append(data)
```

it looks fine till here, now I need to fetch the value for "label"
and the following part doesn't work

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(contents)):
    label= contents[i]['shapes']['label']
    l.append(label)
print(l)
```

Comment: The contents of the .json file shown in your question isn't valid JSON format. It's also a not valid Python representation of a dictionary — so it doesn't "look fine" to me.

Comment: @martineau yes you might be right sorry. I can't share the real json file here, and they are kind of very large. It is a sample or an image of my file. this is my first handling of json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shapes` is a list, so you'll have to iterate over it:

```
l = []
for content in contents:
    for shape in content['shapes']:
        l.append(shape['label'])
print(l)
```